# How can I clone a Git (Stash) repo which is in-premise in my company, on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, git-clone, bitbucket-server

In my company we use Stash for git repository, which is hosted in-premise datacenter. I want to clone a repository on AWS EC2 instance. I have tested the connectivity between ec2 instance and git server and I am able to ping it.

When trying to clone from Stash on an ec2 (RHEL 6) instance I receive an error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 504 while accessing [url removed]

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Here is the command I am using:

```
git clone https://<icode repository url>
```

I can clone the same repository onto my laptop with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a fair amount of cloning repositories on EC2 and it works without a hitch when using SSH for authentication. I create an ssh key (using ssh-keygen) and then register that public key with my git repository (in my case bitbucket or github).

For stash over https it looks like they have a solution using a credentials manager,

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories

Answer (score 0):

504 error is a gateway timeout. Perhaps there's a misconfigured (reverse) proxy in there somewhere